# Custom Cell for UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am trying (but unable to) define a custom style for a `UISearchController` cell. Running the code below results in a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error on the `cell.textlabel?.text` line. Am I missing something completely obvious here?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!
    if (cell != nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
        let data: AnyObject = self.searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as AnyObject
        println("searchresults: \(data)")
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("name") as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("placemark") as? String
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: did you check the value of the key "name" is not nil?

Comment: What is the type of the object in data? Is it a swift type or an Obj-C type?

Comment: BTW, line 5 should be `if cell == nil {` rather than `if (cell != nil) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dequeuing a cell with the identifier "Cell" no matter what. Instead, first check which table view you are in, then dequeue a different cell (with a different identifier) if needed.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks! Wrapping my code in 

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) 

solved the problem.